# My model is not saving with in my database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, model

VIEWS

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views.generic import(ListView, CreateView)
    from models import UserProfileInfo
    from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from forms import UserForm
    
    # Create your views here.
    
    
    class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    
        template_name = "message_app/post_list.html"
    
        form_class = UserForm
    
        model = UserProfileInfo
```

FORMS

```
from django import forms
from models import UserProfileInfo

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = "__all__"
```

POST_LIST.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Please Sign Up</h1>

    <form method="post ">
       {{ form.as_p }}
       {% csrf_token %}

      <input type="submit" value="SignUp">
    </form>

    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I go inside my admin site I can't see an of this information saved

Isn't the create class view already supposed to automatically save it or am I missing something

Comment: Have you called `form_class.save()` yet ?

Comment: I think maybe declaring that password field is screwing with its expected `auto_id` or `name` and the form is being submitted without a required element, making the whole thing fail. You need to override the `post()` method in your view and `print(request.POST)` to see what is being evaluated, and probably you will understand why it fails.

Comment: i think you're missing <form action="your view function"> in html. Check with view side using prints if its actually calling function or not.

Comment: <form method="post " class="user-form"> I hade a space after post that's the reason it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your urls.py, your path is like this

```
path('', UserCreateView.as_view())
```

Comment: I don't have a problem going to the url page but a problem with saving my model in my data base

Answer (score 0):

I had to change a small space in

```
<form method="post " class="user-form"> 
<form method="post" class="user-form">
```